# Which Patterns, best practise in big native build app

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

My point being, I now have *alot* of $(document).on and *alot* of eventlisteners. Doing different things. for each .jsp page, due to phonegap, jquerymobile, and other ajax stuff.

Atm. I split up my project like each .jsp has its own .js file which has a good amount of these listeners, is this the standard pattern, or is there some golden rule that i have overlooked.

Or should I group all my eventhandlers into 1 js file which I load, and then load the methods attached to each of them as we progress through the .jsp pages. Or what is the standard in this field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at MVC Systems for JavaScript like [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/).

Comment: Add a lot of code but it definitely makes it more readable.
thanks